# Assign interval days to their calendar months in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an employee leave record system. In cases where leave spans parts of two calendar months, I need to distribute the days to the months in which they occurred.  For example:

30/Jan/2017 - 3/Feb/2017 (5 Days)

Splitting the 5 days to their months would look like this:

[image: Example]

This was done manually.  How can I do this automatically with formulas?

Comment: Will the dates always cross a month boundary?  Will it always be limited to intervals spanning just two consecutive months?  Might it also span a year boundary?

Comment: no always, but will have this case in live, because this is a leave record system, so that ...

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with a minimum of date functions and date math:

[image: example]

The only formulas are in the output section.

- A8 is just `=A3`
  Displaying just the month name is simply formatting, it's a standard format.
- A9 only needs to display the name of the next month, which again, is formatting, but there are many ways to get a date in the next month.  The formula I used was:

  =DATE(YEAR(A3),MONTH(A3)+1,1)

  That gives you the first day of the month after the date in A3.
- The leave days could all be in the same calendar month, so this is the formula in B8:

  =MIN(DAYSINMONTH(A3)-DAY(A3)+1,B3)

  (This assumes the leave can't be more than a month.)  The formula returns the minimum of the days left in the month or the days entered in B3.
- B9 is the difference between the days in B3 and whatever is calculated in B8 (which can result in zero if the leave doesn't span months):

  =B3-B8

BTW, this works across year boundaries.